# Let $\int_a^bf(x)\text{sgn} (f(x)) + 2f(x) \ \text{d} x = 0$. Show that $f$ has at least one root.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The Assignment:

> Let $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$. Furthermore let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $|f(x)| + |f'(x)| \neq 0$ for $\forall x \in [a,b]$.
>
> Now, let $$\int_a^bf(x)\,\text{sgn}(f(x)) + 2f(x) \ \text{d}x = 0$$
> Show that: $\ f$ has at least one root on the interval [a,b].

I thought about simplifying the integral since $f(x)sgn(f(x)) = f(x)$ and maybe using the additivity of the integral to separate both terms of sums, but I don't know where to go from here. Previously, in the same assignment, I have already shown that $f$ only has a finite amount of roots.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $f(x)sgn(f(x)) = |f(x)|$.

Suppose $f$ is never zero on $[a,b]$. Then by continuity, it's either always positive or always negative. Suppose it's always positive, i.e., $f(x)>0\ \forall x$. Then $|f|=f$, and the integral becomes $3\int_a^b f(x)\ dx$. But this is a positive quantity, because $f$ is positive, and so we get a contradiction, because by hypothesis this must be equal to $0$.

Now suppose $f$ is always negative. Now $|f|=-f$, and the integral becomes $\int_a^bf(x)\ dx$. Again we run into a contradiction: since $f<0$ the integral must be negative, but we assumed at first that it was zero.

The contradiction comes from supposing that $f$ is never zero, and therefore it must happen that for at least one $x$, $f(x)=0$.

As a side note, the condition $|f|+|f'|\neq 0$ wasn't used. Either it's irrelevant, or I missed something.

Comment: Possibly the additional hypothesis is used in other parts of the exercise (the function has only a finite number of roots).